# Border not surrounding the image in div

Tags: css

```
http://74.52.155.226/~projtest/team/harmeet/smoke51/products.html
```

That is the design that i am currently working on. If you inspect element on the banner below the navigation you can see that the 10px solid white border is taking some gap below the image. I am puzzled as to where is that coming from as logically the border should surround the image only no matter what the height of image is.

Comment: i think your border and shadow on .boxshad is creating the problem

Comment: add `display:block` for the image

Comment: No the header. The image with "Starter Kits" text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your image in the `div.innerbanner` is inline (images are inline be default). The space you seen is the [descender height](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_%28typography%29).

You need to create a block element of the image to prevent any descender height to show. Try adding this to your CSS:

```
div.innerbanner img { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can put `display: block;` on your `<img>`

Comment: Thanks all for replies/solution.